# Translate custom attributes with i18next (placeholder, value)

Tags: javascript, localization, globalization, i18next

I am investigating what is possible with [i18next](http://i18next.com/index.html) localization library.

Right now I have the following code ([full Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/dLc7x/)):

**HTML**

```
<div data-i18n="title"></div>
<input placeholder="Hello" value="name">
<div class="holder"></div>
<button class="lang" data-lang="en">Eng</button>
<button class="lang" data-lang="ch">Chi</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    i18n.init({
        "lng": 'en',
        "resStore": resources,
        "fallbackLng" : 'en'
    }, function (t) {
        $(document).i18n();
    });

    $('.lang').click(function () {
        var lang = $(this).attr('data-lang');
        i18n.init({
            lng: lang
        }, function (t) {
            $(document).i18n();
        });
    });
});
```

It translates all `text` elements, but the problem is that I can not translate `custom attributes`. For example text inside the div is translated, but I can not understand how can I translate custom attributes like `placeholder` and `value`.

Another problem is with my way of translation. Whenever a button `Chi`, `Eng` is clicked, I am initializing the translation (but I am not sure this is a correct way). **Edit** I think I found how to solve this problem (I need to use setLng): `i18n.setLng(lang, function(t) { ... })`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After asking [i18next creator](https://github.com/jamuhl) this question directly,  I received the [following reply](https://github.com/jamuhl/i18next/issues/233): all I need is to put my custom attribute in front of the translation element. Here is an example:

```
<div data-i18n="[title]titleTransl"></div>
<input data-i18n="[placeholder]placeTransl" value="name">
```

If multiple attributes are needed, separate them by a `;`.

I learned 2 things by this:

- I have to read better documentation.
- 118next's creator is really helpful (this is a thank you remark for him).

Comment: Suppose, that we've something like this: `<div id="dropdown" class="user_reg">
            <select id="country_list" class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" data-size="5" data-live-search="true" required="required">
                <option value="" disabled class="country_list">Country</option>
            </select>
        </div>`, then how do we translate `Country`?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni in your example here country is not an attribute.

Comment: Yeah, so I tried out this code: `<option id="country" value="" disabled class="country_list">Country</option>` and `$('#country').text($.t('app.country'));`. It worked

Comment: awesome! I expected this to be long winded and fiddly

Comment: also stated in the docs: https://github.com/i18next/jquery-i18next

Comment: there's also a newer blog post tutorial: https://locize.com/blog/jquery-i18next/

Answer (score 11):

For me the following worked

```
<input data-i18n="[placeholder]placeTransl" value="name">
```

So just enter the attribute's name between [] and then the translation.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't get your answer <input placeholder="[placeholder]placeTransl" value="name"> to work. I had to use the data-i18n attribute to get it to work.

Comment: oh sorry, I have not noticed that your answer is different. Really sorry for this. +1

Comment: No problems! Your answer pointed me in the right direction, so thanks!

Comment: I know it's been a while but this doesn't seem to work anymore. Is anyone still using it successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Consider calling

```
$('body').i18n()
```

inside .done() function. You should tell where to look for localizer.
This will work without having to call [placeholders] in the data-i18n attribute.