# Add custom translation inside placeholder attribute with i18next

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, translation, i18next

Is it possible to prepend/append some hardcoded text inside a placeholder? 
e.g we have some text like "Example: " and we want this to appear before translated text in the placeholder.

Original html without prepended/appended static text:

```
<input type="text" data-i18n="[placeholder]translationKEY"/>
```

Related question: [Translate custom attributes with i18next (placeholder, value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728797/translate-custom-attributes-with-i18next-placeholder-value/47085710?noredirect=1#comment81121046_47085710)

Answer (score 0):

Only option i see is custom code or using the nesting feature https://www.i18next.com/nesting.html and nest "Example: " into the value of the "translationKEY"'s value

Comment: Forgot to mention that ideally I should not change any of the namespace translations etc.
I guess custom code means e.g using js/ jQuery to find all these placeholders and add the prefix on attribute?