# i18next - How to change the param value?

Tags: javascript, html, i18next

I need to translate only the tag param value, no the tag value.
Using https://github.com/i18next

OK

`<i data-i18n="skills.photoshop">old value</i>`

NOK

`<a href="??????">link</a>`

Comment: By tag param value, you mean the HTML element attribute value, right? For instance, in `<input placeholder="My Placeholder">` you want to be able to translate the `placeholder` attribute, right?

Comment: Yes! the String "My Placeholder"

Comment: Check out this answer here, maybe it's what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822236/7122251

Comment: @MatheusCanon, You get it! thanks